# Yii2 BeforeAction is bypassed for actions with parameters

Tags: php, yii2

So, here is a quick description of what I have done and the problem I am facing:
I made an access control feature using the beforeAction() in my controller to restrict access for certain user types; in this case "only ADMIN can delete" is the rule I am trying to enforce.
Everything works okay except for actions that have URL parameters. See the code below:

My Controller Behavior

```html
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [

            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'user' => 'staff',
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],

            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    //'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

This is the beforeAction - it checks the role of the logged in user against a list of restricted actions

```html
public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $role = Yii::$app->staff->identity->role;
        $restrictedActions = ['delete', 'create'];
        $allowedUserTypes = ['admin'];

        if(in_array($action->id, $restrictedActions) && !in_array($role, $allowedUserTypes)){
            return $this->redirect(['default/restricted']);
        }

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

The beforeAction restriction works for this:

```html
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Expense();
        $model->created_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $model->created_by = Yii::$app->staff->getId();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

But then doesnt work for this:

```html
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Dump and die ```$action``` in ```beforeAction``` function, and then your if condition, to check if the flow is working fine. If yes, then dump and die ```$id``` inside ```actionDelete``` to test if actionDelete is working as per flow. Hope you find where the intended flow is breaking. :) Happy Coding !!